# Why am I getting a UnicodeDecodeError when installing manim-voiceover?

Tags: python, unicode, manim

I want to install manim-voiceover in a Windows environment, but a UnicodeDecode error occurs. Even though the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable is set to utf-8, the UnicodeDecode error is repeated. Below is the error message.

```
C:\MyFirstFolder>pip install manim-voiceover

Collecting manim-voiceover   Using cached manim_voiceover-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB) Requirement already satisfied: pydub<0.26.0,>=0.25.1 in c:\tools\manim\lib\site-packages (from manim-voiceover) (0.25.1) Collecting mutagen<2.0.0,>=1.46.0 Collecting python-dotenv<0.22.0,>=0.21.0   Using cached python_dotenv-0.21.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB) Collecting humanhash3<0.0.7,>=0.0.6   Using cached humanhash3-0.0.6.tar.gz (5.4 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\FORYOUCOM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7gyhjr68\humanhash3_939d80744ac64b31a109f7a8eb5e4db4\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
          long_description = f.read()
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1081: illegal multibyte sequence
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. hint: See above for details.
```

If anyone knows where to fix it, please comment. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this can help you: (if you use windows)

Find region setting in your control panel. Then click the change system locale. Finally click the box beta and restart.

[image: step to change unicode]